# What process led to the era of Reionization in the early Universe?

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, space-expansion, structure-formation

Reionization was the second major phase transition in the early Universe. At the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reionization#Background) article for the epoch of Reionization in the early Universe, it states:

> The second phase change [i.e., Reionization] occurred once objects started to condense in the early universe that were energetic enough to re-ionize neutral hydrogen.

**Question**: what caused these objects to condense and become energetic enough to reionize neutral hydrogen? Was is gravity? If so, this conceivably had to be sensitive to the immediate environment of local regions of higher-than-average density, to counteract the expansion of space, right? Was it gravity [acting over hundreds of millions of years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reionization#/media/File:Reion_diagram.jpg) during the "dark age" that caused this, or something else?

Comment: UV light from the first stars. I'm surprised the Wikipedia article didn't say that.

Comment: Well, clearly radiation from the first stars caused the Reionization, so I see why my title is not connected with my actual question (I've changed the title, hopefully more clear?)... I'm asking what caused the formation of these first stars. Was it local regions of overdensity that gravitationally collapse and then form stars which radiate to Reionization the diffuse gas around them?

Comment: OK, so you're asking how did the [population III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_population#Population_III_stars) stars form. Yes?

Comment: Yes, and I'm naively wondering about if this was in competition with the expansion of the Universe (or was the energy density of the Universe sufficiently dominated by matter by that time)?

Comment: I think you probably need to ask this as a separate question. As it stands this question does not make it clear that you're really interested in the point at which gravitational contraction into stars first overcame the expansion of the universe.

Answer (score 1):

Reionization began when the first generation of giant stars lit up and started filling space with UV light. Those stars formed by gravitational contraction, triggered by small anisotropies in the distribution of mass in the early universe. It took a while for those stars to form because as they contracted, they heated up and a star forming from nothing but H and He has a difficult time radiating away that heat so it can continue contracting.